# How can I edit locationManager working on background on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm in trouble studying iOS native app on swift.

I'm implementing a function for monitoring iBeacon with locationManager.

When I turn on monitoring in scanning scene and go back to main menu, the monitoring is still scanning iBeacon. But when I move scanning scene and using button for turn on monitoring again,

it will scan double time each checking. Furthermore, I can't stop first one because stop monitoring function always works for current locationManager.

So, I wanna know how to reuse background locationManager I already call before.

Always thanks to every answers.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Your `CLLocationManager` should not be linked to a view controller - it should be in another object that you can use throughout your app

Comment: Thanks to answer. Then How do I stop specific background task ( Monitoring ) ? I wanna only one monitoring task.

Comment: If you only have one location managed then you will only have one monitoring task

Comment: You mean I have to stop monitoring task before I go back to the main menu, because there is no way to stop specific monitoring task in view controller, right?

Comment: No, I mean that if you have one object that manages your location manager and you allocate that object in your main view controller and pass it to subsequent view controllers then it won't be released.

Comment: Thanks to answer :)